# How to remove last border from row which is set by tr?

Tags: html, css

I've a table. The tr is set with a border. I want to remove the last td border from tr.Below is the example

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;">
      <td> adsd </td>
      <td> adsd </td>
      <td> adsd </td>
      <td> adsd </td> <!-- I want to remove the border from this -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any answer would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you really want to achieve... are you using bootstrap?

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap. I just want to remove border css from the last `td` which is set by `tr`.

Comment: What border are you referring to? In your example the last <td> element does not have a border.

Answer (score 9):

## :last-child

> The :last-child selector allows you to target the last element
>   directly inside its containing element. It is defined in the CSS
>   Selectors Level 3 spec as a “structural pseudo-class”, meaning it is
>   used to style content based on its relationship with parent and
>   sibling content.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/

```
table tr td:last-child{
  border:0
}
```

Comment: in my question css is applied to tr . I've tried this but this doesnt work. Are you sure this will work

Comment: If the border is in the **TD** yes. But if your border is in your **TR** you have no chance to remove a border from a **TD**. You should remove the css border from **TR** and add it on every **TD**

Answer (score 3):

`:last-child` Selector

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> a </td>
      <td> b </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> a </td>
      <td> b </td> 
    </tr><tr>
      <td> a </td>
      <td> b </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> a </td>
      <td> b </td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: in my question css is applied to `tr` . I've tried this but this doesnt work. Are you sure this will work

Comment: @jeeva Then put the last-child selector on your tr. Your html is wrong too. Here is the snippet you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **:last-child** pseudo class (details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)).

So your line should look like (assuming you want to remove the bottom border):

```
tr:last-child { border-bottom-style:hidden; }
```

This can be put in a separate css file or between `<style></style>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I understand now what you want and you can achieve that by adding this to your CSS.

```
table tr td:nth-child(4) {
    border: none;
}
```

We will go to your fourth td and remove any border. If you want to remove any border from other  just follow the same logic, replacing the `4` from the td you want.

Comment: in my question css is applied to tr . I've tried this but this doesnt work. Are you sure this will work

Comment: You have your border in the TR, the TD doesn't have a border, what are you expecting to remove then?

Answer (score 0):

Just slap a `border:none` on the `td` element. that will remove the border from the cell,  you may also want to play with `border-right:none`, `border-bottom:none`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;">
      <td> adsd </td>
      <td> adsd </td>
      <td> adsd </td>
      <td style="border:none"> adsd </td> <!-- I want to remove the border from this -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```